# Aligning text in combo boxes using css

Tags: css

I want to align the text inside combo boxes to the left (I'm in RTL mode).

All the combo boxes are inside a div, some other input tags are in the div, I do not want to change their style.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you implementing your combox box? Are you dynamically replacing a select element and a text input with a div and a list? Are you keeping the input element and making a list appear below it (like Google Suggest)? Which text are you talking about? The text in the "text input" part or the "drop down menu" part that it is combined with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#div-id select { text-align: left; }
```